# pandora.com redirects to privateinternetaccess.com

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, proxy, vpn, pandora

I have been playing around with the PIA desktop client and all kinds of VPN settings today, so it's not out of question that something I did screwed something else up, but whatever happened, whenever I now go to pandora.com it automatically directs me to privateinternetaccess.com.

I have restarted chrome, my PC, re-installed chrome, removed the PIA desktop client, removed the tunnelbear desktop client and chrome extension I still had installed and disabled all my other chrome extensions.

Accessing pandora.com through Edge or Chrome's incognito mode works fine.

Visiting http://www.pandora.com/restricted (Which is where I should land when visiting pandora.com, since I'm in Germany and currently w/o a VPN) actually loads the expected page from Pandora. So it's not like the entire domain is bricked.

Kinda out of ideas over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I hadn't tried was just resetting Chrome, since I kinda forgot I can disconnect my Google Account first to not lose all my settings.

So yeah disconnecting google account -> resetting chrome -> reinstalling chrome(cause why not) fixed the issue.